# Changing object value by calling an instance method on that object

Tags: ruby, oop

I want to make a TicTacToe game.  I tried to define an instance method that will change a blank field to `'X'` or `'O'`.

```
class TicTacToe
  attr_accessor :fields, :a1, :a2, :a3, :b1, :b2, :b3, :c1, :c2, :c3

  def initialize
    @a1,@a2,@a3 = " ", " ", " "
    @b1,@b2,@b3 = " ", " ", " "
    @c1,@c2,@c3 = " ", " ", " "
    @fields = {a1: @a1, a2: @a2, a3: @a3, b1: @b1, b2: @b2, b3: @b3, c1: @c1, c2: @c2, c3: @c3}
  end

  def print_table
    p "#{@fields[:c1]}|#{@fields[:c2]}|#{@fields[:c3]}"
    p "#{@fields[:b1]}|#{@fields[:b2]}|#{@fields[:b3]}"
    p "#{@fields[:a1]}|#{@fields[:a2]}|#{@fields[:a3]}"
    p '# # #'
  end
end
game = TicTacToe.new
game.print_table #=> fields[:a1] == ' '

def to_x field
  field = "Y"
end
p to_x game.fields[:a1] #=> fields[:a1] == 'Y'

game.print_table #=> fields[:a1] == ' '
game.fields[:a1] = "X" #=> fields[:a1] == 'X'
game.print_table #=> fields[:a1] == 'X'
```

When I pass a string or a hash objects to it, Ruby raises an error. I want to go the other way around and call my method on an object:

```
field[:a1].to_x
```

How do I do that?

I also tried to extract a method outside of a class, and pass objects to it, but I can't change the variable value. I guess ruby makes another object that references the same object.

What am I doing wrong, and what is proper way to do this?

Comment: _"I want to go other way around"_ – just because of the error?

Comment: *"ruby makes another object that references the same object"* – This sounds like a contradiction to me.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are mutable in Ruby:

```
s = "X"
# => "X"
s[0] = "O"
# => "O"
s
# => "O"
```

So you could write :

```
def to_x field
  field[0] = "X"
end

def to_o field
  field[0] = "O"
end

to_x game.fields[:a1] 
game.print_table 
# " | | "
# " | | "
# "X| | "
# "# # #"
to_o game.fields[:a1]
game.print_table
# " | | "
# " | | "
# "O| | "
# "# # #"
```